# Exporting Data from a Data Table to a XML-File using XSD

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I'm trying as statet above to export my data from a Data Table to a XML-File using my XSD. As I have another Function which import's the Data I would like that the export looks the same, so I generated an XSD out of my Import-XML-File.

The Function to export the data is:

```
public void Export(string CmdString)
    {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, SqlConnector.conn);
            dt = new DataTable("tbl_Adresse");
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dt.WriteXml("..\\..\\..\\XmlDataHandler\\XMLFile_Export.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
    }
```

The Import-XML-File looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<tbl_address>
 <row delete="true" />
 <row Forename="Simon" Surname="Baker" MobileNr="+193434278" />
 <row Forename="Johnny" Surname="Depp" MobileNr="+173953278" />
 <row Forename="Michael" Surname="Jackson" MobileNr="+127425978" />
 <row Forename="Elvis" Surname="Prasley" MobileNr="+163645378" />
 <row Forename="Axl" Surname="Rose" MobileNr="+173975618" />
</tbl_address>
```

The Schema looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

<xs:element name="tbl_address">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="row" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="delete" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

At the moment the Export-XML-File looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="tbl_address" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="tbl_address">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Forename" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="Surname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="MobileNr" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>

 <tbl_address>
  <Forename>Simon</Forename>
  <Surname>Baker</Surname>
  <MobileNr>+193434278</MobileNr>
 </tbl_address
 <tbl_address>
  <Forename>Johny</Forename>
  <Surname>Depp</Surname>
  <MobileNr>+173953278</MobileNr>
 </tbl_address
 <tbl_address>
  <Forename>Michael</Forename>
  <Surname>Jackson</Surname>
  <MobileNr>+127425978</MobileNr>
 </tbl_address
 <tbl_address>
  <Forename>Elvis</Forename>
  <Surname>Prasley</Surname>
  <MobileNr>+163645378</MobileNr>
 </tbl_address
 <tbl_address>
  <Forename>Axl</Forename>
  <Surname>Rose</Surname>
  <MobileNr>+173975618</MobileNr>
 </tbl_address
</NewDataSet>
```

What do I have to change that the Export-File will look the same as the Import-File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now.

The Export-Function looks like this:

```
public void Export(string CmdString)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, SqlConnector.conn);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable("row");
        ds = new DataSet("tbl_adress");
        dt.ReadXmlSchema("..\\..\\..\\XmlDataHandler\\XmlSchema.xsd");
        SqlConnector.da.Fill(dt);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        ds.WriteXml("..\\..\\..\\XmlDataHandler\\XMLFile_Export.xml");
    }
```

and the Schema like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema id="tbl_adress" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="tbl_adress" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="row">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="delete" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="Forename" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="Surname" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="MobileNr" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I created a DataSet named "tbl_adress" and putthe DataTable in this DataSet.
Through this the root-node element is called "tbl_adress".

With the other Answers I got I could solve the problem with the Schema.

Answer (score 1):

Add schema to DataTable

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("tbl_Adresse");
            dt.ReadXmlSchema(fileName);
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);
​
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding schema to your DataTable object (as other answers mention), I believe your schema itself needs tweaking.

I used [XSD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx) to interpret your input XML (as an example) and convert it to XSD schema representation. The schema below is what XSD returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="tbl_address" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="tbl_address" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="row">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="delete" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="Forename" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="Surname" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="MobileNr" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Notice that it differs slightly from your schema as posted.  Please try the two tweaks as suggested (adding schema to the DataTable object PLUS revising the schema to more closely match the data) and report back!

Comment: Now I get an error in the "ReadXmlSchema" Function, that the "DataTable does not match to any DataTable in the source" ...